# split list into 2 lists corresponding to every other element

Tags: python

I know there are many chunky ways to do this, but I am looking for a slick pythonic way to accomplish the following. Given a list of numbers:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

split this list into 2 lists corresponding to every other element:

```
b = [0,2,4,6,8]
c = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want:

```
b = a[::2]  # Start at first element, then every other.
```

and:

```
c = a[1::2]  # Start at second element, then every other.
```

So now we have what we want:

```
>>> print(b)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> print(c)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using list slicing:

```
b = a[::2]
c = a[1::2]
```

#### Example

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>> b = a[::2]
>>> c = a[1::2]

>>> print b
[0,2,4,6,8]

>>> print c
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

The `[::]` syntax is as follows: `[start:end:step]`. If you don't specify any parameters for start and end, it will work with the whole list. Therefore, what the code above is doing is:

For `b`: start at index 0, take every other element from `a`
For `c`: start at index 1, take every other element from `a`

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b=[i for x,i in enumerate(a) if x%2==1]
>>> c=[i for x,i in enumerate(a) if x%2==0]
>>> b
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> c
  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: You are not splitting according to indices, but according to list elements. Just try to split [1,13,75,23,11,17]...

Comment: Okay now. However I would have swapped x and i, it would be more intuitive!